# Moving window search which stops at longest substring matches

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, string-searching

I'm trying to create a search which searches a field for a longest matches possible and then stop.

Here's the basic idea in Python for single match:

```python
import re


def generate(txt: str) -> list:
    s = re.split(r'\s+', txt)
    chunksize = len(s)
    for curr_chunksize in reversed(range(1, chunksize + 1)):
        for pos in range(chunksize - curr_chunksize + 1):
            yield " ".join(s[pos:pos + curr_chunksize])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    txt = 'I think The Thing was great'
    for i in generate(txt):
        print(i)
```

This generates a moving window which gets smaller and smaller:

```
I think The Thing was great
I think The Thing was
think The Thing was great
I think The Thing
think The Thing was
The Thing was great
I think The
think The Thing
The Thing was
Thing was great
I think
think The
The Thing
Thing was
was great
I
think
The
Thing
was
great
```

The search will be:

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    txt = 'I think The Thing was great and Back to the Future too'

    search = ['The Thing', 'The', 'Thing', 'Back to the Future', 'Back to the Future 2']
    # Sort by length, reversed (longest first)
    search = sorted(search, reverse=True, key=lambda x: len(x))

    # longest matches (start pos index, end pos index)
    reserved_substring_range: List[Tuple[int, int]] = []

    for i in generate(txt):
        for s in search:
            if s == i:
                pos = txt.find(s)
                can_add = True
                for r in reserved_substring_range:
                    start, end = r
                    if start <= pos <= end and start <= pos + len(i) <= end:
                        can_add = False
                if can_add:
                    reserved_substring_range.append((pos, pos + len(i)))
                break

    for r in reserved_substring_range:
        start, end = r
        print(txt[start:end])
```

Which outputs:

```
Back to the Future
The Thing
```

Now to PostgreSQL (v15.3) side:

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies (
  id    INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '' CHECK ( title != '' ),
  year  SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK ( year > 0 )
);

INSERT INTO movies (title, year) VALUES 
('The Thing', 1982), ('The Thing', 2011),
('The', 9999), ('Thing', 9999),
('Back to the Future', 9999), ('Back to the Future 2', 9999);
```

Search function which searches from **movies** table and field **title**:

```
SELECT * FROM search('I think The Thing was great and Back to the Future too', NULL::movies, 'title');
```

And it should return:

```
id title              year
5  Back to the Future 9999
1  The Thing          1982
2  The Thing          2011
```

Current attempt which also returns 'The' and 'Thing' incorrectly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search(
    query TEXT, -- search query
    _table ANYELEMENT,  -- source table NULL::<tablename>
    _field TEXT -- source field 'title'
)
    RETURNS SETOF ANYELEMENT
AS $$
DECLARE
    a TEXT[] := regexp_split_to_array(query, '\s+'); -- array of words
    l INT := cardinality(a); -- length of a
    _q TEXT; -- query
    _from INT; -- array start
    _to INT; -- array end
BEGIN
    IF l = 0 THEN
        -- empty query
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    FOR curr_chunk_size IN REVERSE l .. 1 LOOP
        FOR pos IN 0 .. (l - curr_chunk_size) LOOP
            _from := 1 + pos;
            _to := _from + (curr_chunk_size - 1);
            --RAISE LOG 'ccs: %s pos: %', curr_chunk_size, pos;
            _q := array_to_string(a[_from::int : _to], ' ');
            RAISE LOG 'str: "%"', _q;

            RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
                SELECT *
                FROM %s 
                WHERE %I = $1', 
                pg_typeof(_table), _field) 
             USING _q;
  
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

Or is this search possible to create without plpgsql?

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zSxqLhgQ)

Edit: I realized there might be more than one matches.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will satisfy:

```
SELECT id, title, year
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
             movies.id, movies.title, movies.year,
             rank() OVER (ORDER BY length(movies.title) DESC)
      FROM regexp_split_to_array('I think The Thing was great', '\s+') AS ss(a)
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, cardinality(ss.a)) AS u(i)
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, u.i) AS l(i)
         JOIN movies ON title ~ ('\m' || array_to_string(ss[l.i:u.i], '\s+') || '\M')
     ) AS sub
WHERE rank = 1;

 id │   title   │ year 
════╪═══════════╪══════
  2 │ The Thing │ 2011
  1 │ The Thing │ 1982
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I realized there might be more than one match. Question edited and [new Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zSxqLhgQ) with more movies.

Comment: The suggested correct response in your modified question makes no sense: "The Thing" is not the longest match. You have to come up with clear requirements before you can find a solution.